# Installer for Redis Sentinel on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I've installed Redis server v=4.0.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Chris Lea's PPA.
It works great and I set up 2 Slaves. All is good. 
-- Now I want to install and configure Redis Sentinel, but I can't find installers and configuration guide. Google points me to really old stuff. Anyone know where I can find apt-get for Redis Sentinel?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

I think your pkg repo is good, maybe you want to remove/purge your Redis 
and re-install with

```
apt-get --purge remove redis
apt-get install redis-sentinel
```

This will install both Redis as well as Sentinel. I tried this with the same repo `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu xenial main` and works out well.